# how to print range of numbers from 1 to 5 and 16 to 20 by skipping 6 to 15 using for and if else only

Tags: javascript

I wanna print numbers like 1 to 5 then skip numbers from 6 to 15 and then print 16 to 20. Please help me for this question.

```
 var N = 20;

 for(let i=1;i<=N;i++) {
  if(i<=5){
     document.write(i+", ");
  } 

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 const N = 20;

 for (let i=1; i<=N; i++) {
  if(i < 6 || i > 15){
     document.write(i+", ");
  } 

 }
```

To understand this code we can step through what is happening:

1. We assign a variable to the number of times we want to loop.
2. We enter a for loop, which we iterate the number of times we set in step 1
3. For each number, we check if the number is less than 6 OR (`||`) is greater than 15.
4. If it is we print the number since this meets our condition, Otherwise do nothing which will cause the program to move onto the next iteration of the loop (the next number).

Comment: Tristan, this is obviously a homework assignment.  Please explain the `OR` operator to OP so they can understand **why** you did what you did.

Comment: @Zak Agreed, I have updated my answer with additional detail.